# Rails (4) ignores layout when rendering another action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, render

I have a (to me) strange problem:

When rendering the view for "new" the login box is correctly rendered using the layout "box"
however if I try to do it from the action "create" is it rendered as if I set layout => false.

```
class Script::V1::SessionsController < Script::V1::ApplicationController

  layout "box"

  def new
  end

  def create
    _user = User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])

    if _user.nil? then          
        render :new and return
    else
      cookies[:token] = { :value => user.token, :domain => get_cookie_domain, :expires => 1.year.from_now }
      @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
      render 
    end     
  end

# logout
  def destroy
    cookies.delete :token
    redirect_to :new
  end

end
```

I can't figured out what the problem is.

Comment: Why are you using the `return` after `render`?

Comment: try `render :new, :layout => "box"`

Comment: The return statement was a desperate attempt to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved, it might have been caused by some routing issues. either way it works now, thank you for the response.